# Counter in for loop falsely incrementing after execution

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

I have 3 nested loops in which the code doesn't in anyway modify the counters, I need the value of the topmost-level loop counter to use later in the code. It looks like this

```
int i;
for( i = 0; !found && i <f_i.size();i++){
    for(unsigned int j = 0; !found && j < f_g.size();j++){
        for(unsigned int k = 0; !found && k < f_g.size();k++){
            ///Do Stuff
            found = (/*Condition that's fulfilled after 2 iterations on k*/);
        }
    }
}

//Stuff that uses i
```

The condition is fulfilled after 2 iteration of the innermost loop, so `i` has the value 0 at that point.
Using GDB I saw that the value of i jumps to 1 after the condition is checked in the topmost loop, which gives me a wrong later in my program, or worse an out of bounds access.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What part of your code should be preventing `i` from incrementing? The last part of the `for` loop statement is executed at the end of each iteration

Comment: The increment of the `for` will be executed at the end of each iteration, even if the condition prevents the next one from executing.

Comment: Oh, I had no idea, thank you!

Comment: @UnholySheep *"The last part of the for loop statement is executed at the end of each iteration"* ... unless the loop is terminated with a `break` statement. Even a `goto` (*boo, hiss*) will avoid the increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how `for` loops work. The increment is done before the condition is checked.

The proper way (easier to read, easier to maintain) to do what you want is to add a variable, outside the loop.

```
int index;
```

And set it when you find the element:

```
        found = ...
        if (found) index = i;
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable i is incremented due to the third expression of the for loop

```
int i;
for( i = 0; !found && i <f_i.size();i++){
                                    ^^^^  
    for(unsigned int j = 0; !found && j < f_g.size();j++){
        for(unsigned int k = 0; !found && k < f_g.size();k++){
            ///Do Stuff
            found = (/*Condition that's fulfilled after 2 iterations on k*/);
        }
    }
}
```

To avoid this you can write for example

```
int i;
for( i = 0; !found && i <f_i.size();){
    for(unsigned int j = 0; !found && j < f_g.size();j++){
        for(unsigned int k = 0; !found && k < f_g.size();k++){
            ///Do Stuff
            found = (/*Condition that's fulfilled after 2 iterations on k*/);
        }

    }
    i += !found;
}
```

Or instead of the expression statement

```
i += !found;
```

you can use the if statement like

```
if ( !found ) ++i;
```

Also the code will look more readable if the variable `i` will be initialized before the loops for example like

```
int i = 0;
while ( !found && i < f_i.size() ){
    for(unsigned int j = 0; !found && j < f_g.size();j++){
        for(unsigned int k = 0; !found && k < f_g.size();k++){
            ///Do Stuff
            found = (/*Condition that's fulfilled after 2 iterations on k*/);
        }

    }
    i += !found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said (or, at least, *implied*): once the (outermost) `for` loop is entered<sup>†</sup>, the variable, `i`, will be incremented at the end of that loop, **before** the condition is tested, to see if another loop should be run ...

... that is, unless you 'jump out' of the loop using a [`break`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break) statement!

So, the following, slightly modified, code will *not* increment `i` (at all) if `found` becomes `true` during the first iteration of the outermost loop:

```cpp
    int i;
    for (i = 0; !found && i < f_i.size(); i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; !found && j < f_g.size(); j++) {
            for (unsigned int k = 0; !found && k < f_g.size(); k++) {
                ///Do Stuff
                found = (/*Condition that's fulfilled after 2 iterations on k*/);
            }
        }
        // If "found" becomes true, exit the loop immediately, AVOIDING THE INCREMENT:
        if (found) break;
    }
```

So, while the other answers are very good, and the code solutions they offer are perfectly valid, the proposal here is a far more 'minimal' adjustment to your code. I hope it helps.

*Note: You could, of course, add similar `break` statements to the inner loops; however, as your `j` and `k` variables are declared locally to those loops, it would appear that undesired increments to their values is not relevant. Furthermore, `break` cannot be used to jump out of multiple, nested loops.*

<sup>†</sup> Also, be aware that if the `found` variable is `true` *before* the outermost `for` loop is encountered, that loop will not be executed (obviously) and, thus, the `i` variable will not be incremented in that case.